# Не работает вставка фотографии для фона главного окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pillow, pil

У меня не получается поставить свою фотографию как задний фон. 
Вместо этого белый квадрат закрывает все кнопки.

Мой код:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer
from threading import Thread
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import PyQt5

mixer.init()

class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window ):
        window.geometry('320x150'); window.title("Player"); window.resizable(0,0)
        Load = Button(window, text = 'Load',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.load)
        Play = Button(window, text = 'Play',  width = 10,font = ('Times', 10), command = self.play)
        Pause = Button(window,text = 'Pause',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.pause)
        Stop = Button(window ,text = 'Stop',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.stop)
        Volm = Button(window, text = "Volume -", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volm)
        Volp = Button(window, text = "Volume +", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volp)
        GetPos = Button(window, text = "Get Pos" , width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.getPos)
        Timem = Button(window, text = "Time -", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.timeM)
        Timep = Button(window, text = "Time +", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.timeP)
        background = Image.open("background.jpg")
        background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background)
        background_label = Label(window, image=background_image)
        background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        mixer.music.set_volume(1)
        Load.place(x=0,y=20);Play.place(x=110,y=20);Pause.place(x=220,y=20);Stop.place(x=110,y=60); Volm.place(x=0, y=60); Volp.place(x=220,y=60); GetPos.place(x=110, y=100); Timem.place(x=0, y=100); Timep.place(x=220, y=100)
        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False

    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            mixer.music.play()

    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state=True
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False

    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()

    def Volp(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 + 5
        if(volume <= 100):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)

    def Volm(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 - 5
        if(volume >= 0):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)

    def getPos(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        print(pos)

    def timeM(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        mixer.music.play(0,int(pos)-5)

    def timeP(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        mixer.music.play(0,int(pos)+5)

root = Tk()
app= MusicPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer
#from threading import Thread
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#import PyQt5

mixer.init()

class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window ):

        background = Image.open("lena.jpg")             # установите свое изображение
# +++   vvvv
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background)             # +++ self
# +++   vvvv                                        vvvv     
        self.background_label = Label(window, image=self.background_image)
# +++   vvvv
        self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)        

        
        window.geometry('320x150'); window.title("Player"); window.resizable(0,0)
        Load = Button(window, text = 'Load',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.load)
        Play = Button(window, text = 'Play',  width = 10,font = ('Times', 10), command = self.play)
        Pause = Button(window,text = 'Pause',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.pause)
        Stop = Button(window ,text = 'Stop',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.stop)
        Volm = Button(window, text = "Volume -", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volm)
        Volp = Button(window, text = "Volume +", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volp)
        GetPos = Button(window, text = "Get Pos" , width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.getPos)
        Timem = Button(window, text = "Time -", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.timeM)
        Timep = Button(window, text = "Time +", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.timeP)

        mixer.music.set_volume(1)
        
        Load.place(x=0,y=20);Play.place(x=110,y=20);Pause.place(x=220,y=20);Stop.place(x=110,y=60); Volm.place(x=0, y=60); Volp.place(x=220,y=60); GetPos.place(x=110, y=100); Timem.place(x=0, y=100); Timep.place(x=220, y=100)
        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False
        
    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        
    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            mixer.music.play()
            
    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state=True
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
            
    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()
        
    def Volp(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 + 5
        if(volume <= 100):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)
            
    def Volm(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 - 5
        if(volume >= 0):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)
            
    def getPos(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        print(pos)
        
    def timeM(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        mixer.music.play(0,int(pos)-5)
        
    def timeP(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        mixer.music.play(0,int(pos)+5)
        
        
root = Tk()
app = MusicPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @3hhr пожалуйста.